# Register UITapGesture on full width of Horizontal stackview + elements

Tags: ios, swift

I have a horizontal stackView inside a vertical stackView. The problem is that i want to register a UITapGesture on the whole row, not just the elements inside. Since the parent(vertical) stackView 's alignment = .leading, it causes the remaining width not occupied of my stackView to become unresponsive to clicks.

In essence, i'd like for the whole row to be clickable and not just the elements inside of it. I've set the horizontal bg color to black to give an idea of the clickable width.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Here is the general idea of my code:

```
// Parent vertical stackView
private(set) var optionStackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.alignment = .leading
    return stackView
}()

// Child horizontal stackView inside optionStackView
private(set) var takePictureStackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.backgroundColor = .black
    return stackView
}()

...
takePictureStackView.addArrangedSubview(takePictureImageView)
takePictureStackView.addArrangedSubview(takePictureLabel)

optionStackView.addArrangedSubview(takePictureStackView)
...

    // Attaching tapGesture recognizer from VC
takePictureStackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(self.takePicture)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constraint for width of `takePictureStackView` to be equal to the width of `optionStackView`.

This will expand `takePictureStackView` horizontally and will increase the tappable area.

Comment: After you're done with increasing the tappable area, I would also suggest an idea of improvement in terms of cleaner code. What you're trying to achieve using `UIStackView` + `UIImageView` + `UILabel` can be also achieved with a single `UIButton`. A single `UIButton` can have both image and text at the same time. Insets between them are also adjustable. Please check the docs for more info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton

Comment: Very much appreciated!! Thanks for taking the time to help out and suggesting a better practice.